# "Application Failed to Start"

Tags: spring-boot, compiler-errors

I am getting the following exception:

```
2017-05-24 09:41:40.779  INFO 4412 --- [           main] com.develop.NewApplication               : Starting NewApplication on DESKTOP-4GP5JJA with PID 4412 (started by Athira S in C:\Users\Athira S\workspace\new)
2017-05-24 09:41:40.779  INFO 4412 --- [           main] com.develop.NewApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-24 09:41:40.857  INFO 4412 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6a28ffa4: startup date [Wed May 24 09:41:40 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-24 09:41:41.886  INFO 4412 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-05-24 09:41:42.198  WARN 4412 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2017-05-24 09:41:42.214  INFO 4412 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-05-24 09:41:42.214 ERROR 4412 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are dealing with a spring boot application, you have 2 solutions:

**OPTION 1.** If you have a database you can hook up to your application, set the properties group for the spring datasource:

sample application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc://mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
spring.datasource.username=db_username
spring.datasource.password=db_password
```

(The same properties group can be set in yml if you are using that:)

sample application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
    username: db_username
    password: db_password
```

**OPTION 2.** *If you **don't** have a database to connect to*

Remove the dependency on spring-boot-starter-jdbc [or spring-boot-starter-jpa as the jdbc starter is a dependency of the starter jpa]

If you are using maven, that dependency looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In gradle, it'd be something like this:

`compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'`

If this isn't the case for you, please add some more context (such as your pom.xml | build.gradle, and/or application.properties | application.yml so that we can see more of what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

I can not find your question. For this error, you should had some kind of embeded jdbc driver jar, like H2, sqlite, added in your pom. For H2 it is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You don't need version, if you use `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this because my port(8080) was being used in the background. killing that PID did the trick for me